How to Calculate Latitude/Longitude Radius to use for Firestore Database Querying? (X miles from Lat/Long)
Using Xamarin Forms & Firestore, I would like to display locations from my database that are within X amount of miles away from the user.
My database will store the Latitude and Longitude coordinates of every available location and I would like to know if there is a way to calculate an X mile radius latitude and longitude values that I can use to query my database.
In case you are familiar with the concept and not Firestore querying, my database query code will look like this:
var result = await Database.Collection("Map")
           .WhereGreaterThanOrEqualsTo("Latitude", value) //Latitude Minimum
           .WhereLessThanOrEqualsTo("Latitude", value) //Latitude Maximum
           .WhereGreaterThanOrEqualsTo("Longitude", value) //Longitude Minimum
           .WhereLessThanOrEqualsTo("Longitude", value) //Longitude Maximum
           .GetAsync();

Is this the right approach? If so, how can I calculate an X mile radius latitude and longitude values using C#? Also, what would the Firestore query code look like with the given values? If not, what is the correct approach?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-latitude-longitude-x-miles-from-point

Jason has the correct answer. Its a LOT more complicated than simply looking at distances on 2 axes (because these are mapped onto a 3d surface).
If you want a more concise expression of it you could use quaternions but this introduces two issues: rounding inaccuracy and ... the need to understand quaternions. Just stick with what Jason has posted unless what I wrote immediately makes sense to you.

If you don't mind using a third party library. Geofirestore makes these kinds of queries very easy.
